# Trouble with default values of Compass mixin border-radius

Tags: compass-sass

I'm using Compass 0.12.2 which uses this code for its `border-radius` mixin:

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_border-radius.scss

As easy to see, the default value for the argument `$radius` is set with the variable `$default-border-radius` which is defined at top of the file.

Then why does this

```
@include border-radius; // or @include border-radius();
```

throw the error *Mixin border-radius is missing argument $radius* ?

Shouldn't it use the default value?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused by [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) defining its own `border-radius` mixin, which was overriding the compass one.